# How can I connect my ionic app to cpanel node server?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, cpanel, ionic4, node-mysql

I'm developing an ionic  app which has to be connect with cpanel node.js mysql server. when server runs in cpanel it shows as server is running. but I can't send requests from my app to the server. I'm confused with the server IP and port.

for node js server index.j file I have used port 3000 and host as localhost including mysql db username and pw. I tried to get response by using 
url:http://(my cpanel Ip):3000/

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "bdruser",
    password: "ABCD",
    database: "users",
    multipleStatements: true
});

when I send the requests by using postman it shows as could not get any response

Comment: I think you are confusing with database thing. This has nothing to with data base. First check your server port is open from firewall. If it is not open, open the port 3000 from firewall.

Comment: yes  you were right . thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you are miles off from getting this right, and I can't give a simple fix:

- You must use `https` for feeds or Android won't play nice.
- You cannot connect to a mysql because then the servers password would be in your apps code and be a security risk
- You are not connecting to the server in the right way anyway, localhost would only work if you were running that code on the same server as the mysql database.
- Node.js is not for using within Ionic apps.

What you need to do is something different but its not simple:

- Set up a website on your cpanel server
- Set up a webservice on there
- Secure the webservice in a way that you can access it from Ionic
- Connect the webserver to the mysql database
- Write code to expose the data you want through the service

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue. Whats wrong was firewall has blocked my port 3000. After it unblocked now my app is working very well with the cpanel backend server.

Thanks!!